# Execute window[func].apply(this, args)

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I am trying to execute a function stored in a variable and pass params to it. However, on the `.apply` line, I am getting an error; `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/valamas/vzesm/

```
function target(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}

function mainfunc (func)
{
    var args = new Array();
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
        args.push(arguments[i]);

    console.log('args: ' + args);

    //-- different attempts
    window[func].apply(this, args);
    //window[func].apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    //this[func].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}


$(function ()
{
    console.log('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n');
    console.log('ready');
    mainfunc('target', 'hello,', 'there!');
});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsFiddle doesn't put the JS into the global scope, so `target` isn't actually a property of `window`.

Adding this code will make your script work:

```
window.target = target;
```

Or to be more explicit:

```
window.target = function() { ...
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/vzesm/3/**

Comment: wherever it puts it, if you change onload to "no wrap - head" it works

Comment: It probably wraps it with a `(function() { ... })();` wrapper. I didn't know about the no wrap option, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in jsfiddle javascript gets executed in a different scope. **Your code will work in firebug console** if jQuery is loaded. For jsfiddle you have to rewrite as given below

```
target = function(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}

function mainfunc (func)
{
    var args = new Array();
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
        args.push(arguments[i]);

    console.log('args: ' + args);

    //-- different attempts
    window[func].apply(this, args);
    //window[func].apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    //this[func].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}


$(function ()
{
    console.log('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n');
    console.log('ready');
    mainfunc('target', 'hello,', 'there!');
});
```